# How can I modify default project location in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

My default Intellij project location is desktop, how can I modify it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In last versions if you created brand new empty project then after restarted IDE will offer that last path as default path by default.

Since the version **IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 EAP**

> ability to specify the default directory for opening projects. In the **Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings** in the Project Opening section there is a new **Default directory** field where you can set a directory.